# How To Open a Map Overlay on Marker Click in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Im really curious how rolex pulled this slick interaction of. Here is a video example of what im interest in recreating.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0gVE.jpg

If you have any tips and hints on how to pull this of please shoot me a message.

Thanks!

Comment: You can start looking at the events part of the API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events.
Then it's a classical DOM manipulation to display something from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. Just create an object, with each id of marker, and associate them when creating your view for retrieving your data each marker is selected.
For creating your view, just set `z-index`, or `position: absolute`, for example, or just `float`. Do you understand?